# I clicked Replace instead of Merge and it wiped the folder. Where did my files go?

Tags: finder, folders, file-transfer

I had about 4gb of important files inside 'Folder A' in Documents. I tried to transfer some files from my external drive to 'Folder A', so I copied the whole folder from my external drive, and it prompted me with a *Stop, Replace, Merge* dialogue box.

Coming from Windows, I had assumed that **Replace** meant to '*replace existing files of the same filename*,' but this does not seem to be the case.

When I clicked **Replace**, the files did get transferred over as I expected, but the original contents of 'Folder A' has been wiped. I tried to undo the move with ⌘+Z in the finder, but with that, the entirety of 'Folder A' is now missing from Documents.

I tried to search the Trash with no luck.

Where did the original files go? How can I get them back?

Comment: RE: "Where did the original files go? How can I get them back?" --  They are gone and you'll need to restore them from your latest backup.

Comment: I tried to use Time Machine but apparently there are no backups saved. Does that mean my files are now totally permanently deleted...?

Comment: Were you *making* backups with Time Machine?  Also, when Finder prompts you, it is referring to the object you are manipulating, not anything else.  So yes, it replaced the one object (the directory) with the other